# Throwing an exception while handling an exception

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm reading the "C++ Programming Language 4th edition" book and have a question regarding a paragraph about exception handling:

> There are cases where exception handling must be abandoned for less
>   subtle error-handling techniques. The guiding principles are:
>
> - Don't throw an exception while handling an exception.
> - Don't throw an exception that can't be caught.
>
> If the exception-handling implementation catches you doing either, it
>   will terminate your program.

Could someone give me an example of the first situtation? Only something like this comes to my mind but it's a valid code according to g++:

```
try
{
    throw 1;
}
catch(...)
{
    try
    {
        throw 2;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "OK";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not assume something is valid and/or does what you think just because it compiled! `C++` has the concept of [*undefined behaviour*](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213), which roughly translates as "if you do something invalid, all bets are off". It may crash, it may work, it may appear to work but send all your credit card numbers to Nigerian princes. Note I'm not saying this particular case is (I think it's not UB, just dangerously close), but don't think "it compiled, it's fine".

Comment: I can't agree withthe first of these, but can heartily agree with the second. There are *many* times catch-blocks can throw exceptions, including the same exception (via `throw;`).

Comment: Text continues: Note that an exception is considered handled immediately upon entry into a catch-clause.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a bit misleading; it's fine to throw from an exception handler (which is what I'd understand by "while handling an exception"), as long as there's another handler to catch it.

The problem is if you throw an exception from the destructor of an object that's being destroyed during stack unwinding. In that case, there are two unhandled exceptions, and the usual exception mechanism can only deal with one; so the response is to call `terminate`.

Example:

```
struct dodgy {~dodgy() {throw "Don't do this!";}};

try {
    dodgy d;
    throw 1;
} catch (...) {
    // Never reached: destroying `d` killed the program.
}
```

Comment: +1 for the point on destructor behavior in a multi-throw environment. Not often considered, yet often a problem. Nice writeup.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found far more detailed explanation in the standard - it's 15.5.1/1.

Comment: You can use `std::uncaught_exception` to see if throwing an exception will kill the program.

Comment: @Steztric: Dividing by zero (almost certainly) won't throw an exception; it gives undefined behaviour, typically raising a signal - which is very different to a C++ exception. Throwing an exception from a handler (i.e. a `catch` block) is fine, as I said.

Comment: According to [this page](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BewareOfExceptionsInTheDestructor) in C++11 `terminate` is also called even when throwing destructor isn't participating in a stack unwinding. However, 15.5.1/1 says the opposite - "when the destruction of an object during stack unwinding terminates by throwing an exception" `terminate` is called. It's a bit odd.

Comment: @Quentin: That Wiki page is wrong. As you say, 15.5.1/1 enumerates all the reasons for calling `terminate`, and it doesn't happen on *all* throwing destructors, just when unwinding the stack or destroying a static or thread-local object.

Comment: But I got `terminate` called after executing this
`struct A { ~A(){throw 1;} };
try{A a;}catch(...){ }`

Comment: @Quentin: Really? [I didn't](http://ideone.com/vEPpzw). Either you executed something different, or your compiler is doing something non-standard.

Comment: I assure you I did get this message in g++ 4.8.1 - "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int' Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: @Quentin: Mystery solved: I didn't know that, in C++11, destructors are implicitly declared `noexcept` unless you provide an explicit exception specifier. So the Wiki is half correct; a destructor can't throw unless you deliberately override the implicit specifier. See 15.4/14 for the gory details.